# Querying for entities that match a collection in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

imagine I have two entities - Tag and Text where Text has multiple tags and there are several things I would like to do with them. I would be very happy if you can help me come up with an elegant solution.

I want to search for Text entities by multiple Tags at once - all tags must match

I want to search for Text entities by multiple Tags, second parameter specifies how many must mach

I would like to specify pairs or triplets of tags where at least one of every pair must match

Any suggestions? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answers to these are pretty much the same, whether you use SQL, HQL or JPQL:

> I want to search for Text entities by
>   multiple Tags at once - all tags must
>   match

```
where text like %tag1% and text like %tag2% // etc.
```

> I want to search for Text entities by
>   multiple Tags, second parameter
>   specifies how many must mach

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(int i = 0; i < howmany; i++){
   sb.append('%').append(param);
}
sb.append('%');

String query = "some query text where " + sb.toString()
```

> I would like to specify pairs or
>   triplets of tags where at least one of
>   every pair must match

```
where text like %tag1% or text like %tag2% -- etc
```